# How can I prevent my unhidden HtmlTableRows from hiding again after the page is submitted?

Tags: c#, jquery, html-table, form-submit, hidden

I'm using an HtmlButton to make some HtmlTableRows that have been hidden visible. The HtmlButton is created and set up like so:

```
HtmlButton btnAddFoapalRow = null;
. . .
btnAddFoapalRow = new HtmlButton();
btnAddFoapalRow.Attributes["type"] = "button";
btnAddFoapalRow.InnerHtml = "+"; 
btnAddFoapalRow.ID = "btnAddFoapalRow";
this.Controls.Add(btnAddFoapalRow);
```

I then create HtmlTableCells programmatically, add those cells to dynamically created HtmlTableRows, and then add the HtmlTableRows to an HtmlTable.

Rows 3 and 4 start off life hidden under a bushel (so to speak):

```
foapalrow3.Style["display"] = "none";
. . .
foapalrow4.Style["display"] = "none";
```

The above happens server-side/C#; I respond to btnAddFoapalRow's click in jQuery to make the next hidden row, as long as there is one, unhidden/visible:

```
/* This makes the next hidden row visible, as long as there is one */
$(document).on("click", '[id$=btnAddFoapalRow]', function (e) {
    $('[id$=foapalhtmltable]').find('tr:hidden:first').show();
});
```

This works slicker than Grace. The problem is that when I submit the form, the HtmlTable reverts back to only showing its initial two rows (header row and one data row); the one or two additional data rows I've added by clicking btnAddFoapalRow "go invisible" again (revert to "display:none" apparently). If I re-click btnAddFoapalRow, the rows reappear with any entered data still intact -- so they haven't really been 86'd, they're just being shy -- but how can I prevent these rows from folding up/hiding at all?

Comment: You need to persist *any* UI changes to the server (or at least local browser storage) for it to survive a page refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going with what @TrueBlueAussie said in the comments, you need to have the fact that the form has been submitted persist through a page load.

You can either handle that somehow on the server side (DB Update perhaps) or to make it simpler you could just create a cookie with JavaScript.

Comment: Always opting for the simpler route, I am exploring the cookie option; where would/should the reading of the cookie take place - in $(window).load() ?

Comment: I asked a related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31392190/why-is-my-ready-function-not-reached