# Why are my rows not visible after being set to visible?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, css

I have a table that has six rows, but starts off with only two of them visible (a header row and one "business" row).

The user can select a button that adds additional rows one at a time (actually, it just makes an existing row visible), up to a total of the six rows / five "business" rows.

Rows 2-6 are made invisible at first by this code-behind:

```
foapalrow3.Style["display"] = "none";
```

(with the same code for foapalrow4, foapalrow5, and foapalrow6).

They are then made visible via jQuery like so when the user selects the "+" button:

```
/* This makes the next hidden row visible, as long as there is one */
$(document).on("click", '[id$=btnAddFoapalRow]', function (e) {
    $('[id$=foapalhtmltable]').find('tr:hidden:first').show();
});
```

This works fine. The problem is, when the form is submitted, the previously visiblized rows revert back to being hidden (all but the first two). I'm trying to add code that will re-visiblize these rows *if* any text input in them was given a value. IOW, if I give the "Index" column a value in each row like so:

[image]

....I would hope that they would be made visible again, because they *do* have a value:

[image]

...and their visible property is indeed "true":

[image]

...but the rows remain recalcitrant, hiding in their burrows. This is the code behind for that:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        . . . // code elided for brevity
        ConditionallyCreateList();
        SaveInputToList();
        listOfListItems = ReadFromList();
        message.Text = "Saving the data has been successful";

        // Expose any rows with vals
        if (RowContainsVals(3))
        {
            foapalrow3.Visible = true;
        }
        if (RowContainsVals(4))
        {
            foapalrow4.Visible = true;
        }
        if (RowContainsVals(5))
        {
            foapalrow5.Visible = true;
        }
        if (RowContainsVals(6))
        {
            foapalrow6.Visible = true;
        }

        . . . // code elided for brevity
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        message.Text = String.Format("Exception occurred: {0}", ex.Message);
    }
}

private bool RowContainsVals(int rownum)
{
    bool rowdirty = false;
    switch (rownum)
    {
        case 3:
            rowdirty = ((!String.IsNullOrEmpty(boxFund2.Text)) ||
                (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(boxIndex2.Text)) ||
                (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(boxOrganization2.Text)) ||
                (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(boxAccount2.Text)) ||
                (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(boxActivity2.Text)) ||
                (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(boxAmount2.Text)));
            break;
        case 4:
            rowdirty = ((!String.IsNullOrEmpty(boxFund3.Text)) ||
                (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(boxIndex3.Text)) ||
                (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(boxOrganization3.Text)) ||
                (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(boxAccount3.Text)) ||
                (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(boxActivity3.Text)) ||
                (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(boxAmount3.Text)));
            break;
        case 5:
            rowdirty = ((!String.IsNullOrEmpty(boxFund4.Text)) ||
                (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(boxIndex4.Text)) ||
                (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(boxOrganization4.Text)) ||
                (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(boxAccount4.Text)) ||
                (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(boxActivity4.Text)) ||
                (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(boxAmount4.Text)));
            break;
        case 6:
            rowdirty = ((!String.IsNullOrEmpty(boxFund5.Text)) ||
                (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(boxIndex5.Text)) ||
                (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(boxOrganization5.Text)) ||
                (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(boxAccount5.Text)) ||
                (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(boxActivity5.Text)) ||
                (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(boxAmount5.Text)));
            break;
        default:
            rowdirty = false;
            break;
    }
    return rowdirty;
}
```

However, this is all I see after that code runs:

[image]

So why does setting the visible property to visible not indeed set them visible?

### UPDATE

NOTE: If I re-expand the rows via the "+" button, they *do* contain the values I added to them. So the rows live and retain their data, they just don't want to show themselves...

Comment: see if in your page_load you have all your logic in if(!IsPostBack), also how is your markup?, Control.Visible = false is not the same as Control.Style["display"] = "none", when a control visible = false, it is not renderer on the client side, while dispay none will but will hide it on the client side

Comment: Can you expand on the first part - I do not have an IsPostBack - is that a standard bool function I can call, or is that a custom method?

Comment: thats the standard bool. just use if(!Page.IsPostBack){}

Comment: Instead of setting Visible = true, should I be: foapalrow3.Style["display"] = "table-row"; ?

Comment: @Mr.: Your note about visible = false not being the same thing as display = [the opposite of none] is what led to my solving the conundrum. Make that an answer, and I will mark it as such.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon I will, glad it helped you

Comment: It's like you crafted this post with the thought of using this word: "recalcitrant" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your code to use `Style["display"] = "table-row";` instead of `Visible = true;`

You say that in code behind rows are made "invisible" by setting the style `display:none.`

Note that in asp.net making a control.Visible **is NOT the same** that making it invisible with an style.

`Control.Visible = false` will not render the HTML code on the Client Side while setting the `display:none` will do render it with an style that hides that rows on the browser. I assume this is yor case as you say that you hide and show the rows on the client side and in order to do that they must exist on the client side so I assume in no place in your code they are `Visible = false;`

Answer (score 0):

Changing my code from this:

```
// Expose any rows with vals
if (RowContainsVals(3))
{
    foapalrow3.Visible = true;
}
if (RowContainsVals(4))
{
    foapalrow4.Visible = true;
}
if (RowContainsVals(5))
{
    foapalrow5.Visible = true;
}
if (RowContainsVals(6))
{
    foapalrow6.Visible = true;
}
```

...to this:

```
// Re-visiblize any rows that contain vals
if (RowContainsVals(3))
{
    foapalrow3.Style["display"] = "table-row";
}
if (RowContainsVals(4))
{
    foapalrow4.Style["display"] = "table-row";
}
if (RowContainsVals(5))
{
    foapalrow5.Style["display"] = "table-row";
}
if (RowContainsVals(6))
{
    foapalrow6.Style["display"] = "table-row";
}
```

...works.